# Lilypond: B-note stem up

Tags: notation, sheet-music, lilypond

I want B note to have its stem going up most of the time so I don't need to use every time \stemUp and \stemNeutral commands.
Is that possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\override Stem.neutral-direction = #UP` as given in the first snippet here: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/inside-the-staff#stems

Comment: Is `#UP` different to `#up` in any way?  Capital letters looks/feels nicer for some reason, but it's not what they use in the documentation (in that snippet).

Comment: @ElementsinSpace They are both naught but syntax candy for `1`. You can see this by executing `#(display UP)` or `#(display up)`. Similarly `DOWN` stands for `-1`. `LEFT` and `RIGHT` are also syntax candy for `-1` and `1`. So you could also say `\override Stem.neutral-direction = #RIGHT` if you want :). This is a direction value (what in Lilypond code is called drul (down/right/up/left) value), the interpretation for which depends on the axis in question.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Also if we talk about axes: `X` is syntax candy for `0` and `Y` is syntax candy for `1`. So we could in fact even write `\override Stem.neutral-direction = #(/ (- Y LEFT) 2)` or something, if you intend to annoy everyone trying to read your code :)

Comment: So, lowercase letters are being used in the snippet because it's *slightly* more "human friendly".  
Whereas, you're using uppercase letters because it's *slightly* more explicit that these terms are just monikers for low level integers.  
Right?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Nah, I’m using uppercase versions because I’m used to it, and it is consistent with things like `X`. This way everything that is uppercase can be seen as a constant, everything else would be a function.

Comment: `#up` exists for historical reasons, I believe. Virtually everything in LilyPond uses the convention `#UP`.

Comment: @ABOUSAMRAJean *Except* for this snippet in the documentation, as it seems. But then this first appears in documentation with version 2.8, introduced by Graham Percival in February 2006. That’s quite some time ago, I was 12 back then ...